# Php code compatibility version 5.2 to 5.4

Tags: php, apache

I'm currently using a PHP Version 5.2.5. I want to upgrade my php to PHP version 5.4.35 and my apache 2.0.5(no ssl) to apache 2.2.25 (open ssl). Does my code compatible with the current and the latest version or should i rewrite my code to be compatible? Help.. pls Thank you..

Comment: Without looking at your code it's hard to say. It's likely a lot of your code won't work. Your best bet would be to create a test environment with the configuration you specify and test it out yourself.

Comment: Thanks for ur response sir, uhm i already upgraded the apache and php at first it seems ok the front page of the website is displayed but when i click on the links, the url is present in the address bar but the page still reloads on the first page.